# Wrong sorting of non-English characters (iTunes 11.2 for Windows)

Tags: itunes, windows, sort

Since version 11.2 of iTunes for Windows, I am experiencing a problem with sorting of names with non-English characters (such as ž, š, č, ř or other in Czech). It seems that iTunes completely omits these characters when sorting. As an example, I have Čajkovskij (which is the Czech spelling of Tchaikovsky) among artists in my library and it is currently sorted between Adele and Alan Parsons Project, i.e. it seems that the character Č has been completely omitted while sorting and thus the artist is sorted as Ajkovskij.

All my ID3 tags are of version 2.3 and in Unicode, thus this should not be any encoding problem. I even tried to change the ID3 tags to version 2.4, i.e. UTF-8, and it did not help.

I think that there must be many more people experiencing this problem. Not everyone has only English or ASCII names in the library and I am surprised that I could not find anything on this bug anywhere on the net yet.

Is anyone else experiencing this? Do you think it is a bug of the iTunes software? Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
I concurrently added this question to the Apple Discussion forums and it seems that it might possibly really be a bug in the latest version of iTunes for Windows.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6387079

Comment: only in iTunes or elsewhere as well ?

Comment: I changed the question appropriately to take into account that I’ve been talking about iTunes for Windows all the time. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Consequently I removed my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

iTunes has a Sort tab in the info panel. In this panel, the fields on the right side are used to sort songs. Check it.

For example, my song *עוד לא אהבתי די* has a Sort Title set to *Od Lo Ahavti Dai*, so the song appears between *Octopus's Garden* and *Ode To My Family*.